# Give an example of a two variable function which is not continuous at (1,2)

Tags: calculus, vectors

Give an example of a two variable function which is not continuous at (1,2)

Is this possible? Since the point can be approached from any angle (infinity), doesn't that mean that all points can be approached some way or another?

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{x - 1}$? Included in two-variable functions are one-variable functions where you "forget" the second variable. This gives an easy source of counterexamples.

A more localized function might be $g(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{(x-1)(y-2)}$, which "feels" less like cheating.

You might do it even simpler by not building it out of formulas. Consider the function $h(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \neq (1,2)$, and $h(x,y) = 1$ at $(1,2)$. This is analogous to a "jump" discontinuity.